# Excel VBA IsDate function mistakes text for date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to perform date calculations in Excel VBA, but I'm getting a runtime error 13 (type mismatch) even though Excel's IsDate() returns true.

In Excel, I have the following data  
A2 : enter "5/20" displays as "20-May"  
A3 : enter "5/20 12:00 p" displays as "2019/05/20 12:00"  
A4 : enter "5/20 12:00p" displays as "5/22 12:00p"  
  
I have verified that cells A2 and A3 can be displayed as a number instead of a date.  Cell A4 only displays as text/string, but the VBA IsDate() still passes on A4.

```
Private Sub Date_Errors()
Dim MyRng As Variant
Set MyRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "A4")
For Each cell In MyRng
    If IsDate(cell) Then ' make sure the cell has a date
        If cell.Value < Date Then
            MsgBox ("Before")
        ElseIf (cell.Value - 1) < Date Then
            MsgBox ("Older")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not a date")
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

MsgBox's get displayed properly for cells A2 and A3, but the mismatch error comes on the "ElseIf (cell.value - 1)" line.  Why isn't IsDate(cell) catching this and falling through to the Else?

Comment: *Why isn't IsDate(cell) catching this and falling through to the Else?* Because that's not how `IsDate` works. The value you've got actually *can* be parsed as a date. Your problem is not related to that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From microsoft help:

```
Dim MyVar, MyCheck
MyVar = "04/28/2014"    ' Assign valid date value.
MyCheck = IsDate(MyVar)    ' Returns True.

MyVar = "April 28, 2014"    ' Assign valid date value.
MyCheck = IsDate(MyVar)    ' Returns True.

MyVar = "13/32/2014"    ' Assign invalid date value.
MyCheck = IsDate(MyVar)    ' Returns False.

MyVar = "04.28.14"    ' Assign valid time value.
MyCheck = IsDate(MyVar)    ' Returns True.

MyVar = "04.28.2014"    ' Assign invalid time value.
MyCheck = IsDate(MyVar)    ' Returns False.
```

In other words, it will catch anything ressembling to a date, but actually you have a string so you can't substract 1 from a string. The solution?

```
Dim MyDate As Date
If IsDate(Cell) Then
MyDate = Cell
```

Then you use `MyDate` instead `Cell`

Comment: @mikepl don't forget to mark it as correct so the question can be closed as answered.